# "A cheap and dirty solution" - help me offend someone

Tags: american-english, connotation

Looking for one word with a negative connotation to describe "a cheap and dirty solution" in a professional (software) environment.

"The proposed solution is (a) ...."

Basicly synonyms of: "The proposed solution is shitty", "The proposed solution is bogus", "The proposed solution is bullshit".

Comment: [A horrible, horrible hack](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/73334/what-is-a-hack).

Comment: How important is it to maintain sang-froid (on both sides)?

Comment: "Help me offend someone" :D

Comment: Your question is not clear. A *cheap and dirty solution* is not necessarily a bad thing. I sometimes offer solutions of this type, and may label them as *cheap and dirty* myself. The important part here is that a cheap and dirty solution is a *solution* (i.e. it solves the problem). It does **not** fit any of your proposed synonyms.

Comment: @Dan, it isn't.

Comment: @michael.hor257k the fact that a "cheap and dirty" doesn't express a bad thing is my issue. I'm looking for a word to better describe it.

Comment: @Reinard But you haven't really told us what "it" is.

Comment: A [bodge](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bodge) in British English. It depends who you are talking to.

Comment: is it actually a solution, or not?

Comment: "Cheap and nasty" is a phrase I am familiar with that echos this. It usually means little work has gone into the product, and the product will produce a low quality effect and break quickly.

Comment: This might not be as insulting as you want, but: ***cut-rate***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For software development in particular, [kludge](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/K/kludge.html) comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something *offensive*, and *synonymous with shitty*, I'd suggest **"crappy"**

**"The proposed solution is so crappy!"**

> - [**crappy**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crappy) - inferior, worthless.

Comment: You can hit them with a bit of a pun by making it "POC."  The acronym can be either **P**roof **O**f **C**oncept or **P**iece **O**f **C**rap.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to offend might I suggest *simplistic*, or *naive* both suggest the solution has not been thought through.

If it works, but could be done  better how about *inelegant*.

Or to damn with faint praise *workmanlike*.

Answer (score 0):

Jury-Rigged or Jerry-rigged speaks to an expedient if ugly solution to a problem. If one uses the term "Jerry-Rigged" you might be able to offend those of German descent.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jerry%E2%80%93rigged

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jury_rigging

In many cases the solution is "good enough" to get the job done until a professional repair can be undertaken.

Answer (score 0):

*Bubble gum and bailing wire* is a hoary way of characterizing a just-good-enough-to-get-home auto repair.  It's an analogous situation.